# Three Char Month and Culture matching in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a multi cultural website, where I allow users to enter values in a dd-MMM-yyyy format. I am able to determine the different values based upon their culture in C# (May, English = May, German = Mai)

the problem I am having is the javascript validation of these months. I am able to build the list of acceptable values:

english:

```
^Jan$|^Feb$|^Mar$|^Apr$|^May$|^Jun$|^Jul$|^Aug$|^Sep$|^Oct$|^Nov$|^Dec$
```

German:

```
^Jan$|^Feb$|^Mrz$|^Apr$|^Mai$|^Jun$|^Jul$|^Aug$|^Sep$|^Okt$|^Nov$|^Dez$
```

I just want to make this regular expression case insensitive. but all the references I see are all pointing me to the /gi flag, but I all of the examples make no sense. I have tried the following and it just doesn't work:

```
var shouldMatch = "may";
var regexPattern = "^Jan$|^Feb$|^Mar$|^Apr$|^May$|^Jun$|^Jul$|^Aug$|^Sep$|^Oct$|^Nov$|^Dec$/gi"
if(shouldMatch.match(regexPattern) != null) {
    //this should happen
}
```

What am I doing wrong? the regex help out there for javascript is killing me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/EmAAR/)***

But what about trying to match "mAR" or "MAr", etc.? This quickly becomes an interesting scenario. In my opinion, an easy way to do this is to just match to upper case

```
var shouldMatch = "May";
var regexPattern = "^JAN$|^FEB$|^MAR$|^APR$|^MAY$|^JUN$|^JUL$|^AUG$|^SEP$|^OCT$|^NOV$|^DEC$";
if(shouldMatch.toUpperCase().match(regexPattern) != null) {
 alert("match");
}
```

Comment: This is how I ended up fixing this problem. btw, thanks for the jsfiddle example. great answer!

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression should **not** be a string:

```
var shouldMatch = "may";
var regexPattern = /^Jan$|^Feb$|^Mar$|^Apr$|^May$|^Jun$|^Jul$|^Aug$|^Sep$|^Oct$|^Nov$|^Dec$/i;
if(shouldMatch.match(regexPattern) != null) {
    // this seems happened
}
```

Comment: +1, though a string can be used with the RegExp consructor. But you're on the right track with using a literal.

Comment: this has to be the uglies string i have ever seen. is there a more elegant way of doing this? Patterns like this just make javascript look so ugly

Comment: sorry, I didn;t want this to come across as negative. but Regular expressions just have become another data value, rather than code. so when I see javascript like my stomach flip flops. the hardest thing i see with this is understanding how the or operator and the /gi operator work together. there is no clear order of operations defined.

Comment: @NathanTregillus Yap `/^(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)$/i`

Answer (score 1):

`regexPattern` is a string, not a regular expression.

Convert it to a RegExp before you use it with match:

```
var regexPattern = new RegExp("^JAN$|^FEB$|^MAR$|^APR$|^MAY$|^JUN$|^JUL$|^AUG$|^SEP$|^OCT$|^NOV$|^DEC$", "gi");
```

And also, convert the `shouldMatch` to upper case before you use it:

```
shouldMatch = shouldMatch.toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

Changed to using [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

No need for the global "g" flag as you are testing the whole string from beginning "^" to end "$"

Changed string `regexPattern` into a [RegExp object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

The "i" flag is needed because you want case insensitive.

Javascript

```
var shouldMatch = "may";
var regexPattern = /^Jan$|^Feb$|^Mar$|^Apr$|^May$|^Jun$|^Jul$|^Aug$|^Sep$|^Oct$|^Nov$|^Dec$/i;
if(regexPattern.test(shouldMatch)) {
    alert(shouldMatch);
}
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/tPYF9/)

You could also make it a little shorter and a little less ugly by doing this

```
var regexPattern = /^(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)$/i;
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/GuYEF/)

As an alternative to regex, you could also use [String.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and [Array.some](http://array.some), and try each pattern to see if it is in the string you are testing. This example will require a modern browser or a "shim"/"polyfill" for older browsers. You could also check equality "===" if you want to match the whole string rather than see if it is contained in.

Javascript

```
var shouldMatch = "may";
var patterns = "Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec".split("|");
var matched = patterns.some(function (pattern) {
    if (shouldMatch.toLowerCase().indexOf(pattern.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
        alert(shouldMatch);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
});
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/aEfmQ/)

Answer (score 0):

Or run the possibilities together-

```
var Rx=/^(jan|feb|m(ar|rz)|apr|ma[iy]|jun|jul|aug|sep|o[ck]t|nov|de[cz])$/i

Rx.test('may');
```

Comment: that would work for both German and English, but I've got 30+ cultures supported by the website. My end solution was to build the regex on the server where it is easy to build the month list, and populate it into a global variable in the javascript